# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 error while compiling with clang

Tags: objective-c, macos, clang

I am trying to compile a [simple project](https://github.com/mattt/DictionaryKit) (program `main.m` and a library `TTTdictionary.m`), but it gives me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main-dba0a1.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTTDictionary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main-dba0a1.o
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
      _main in main-dba0a1.o
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
      _main in main-dba0a1.o
  "_objc_enumerationMutation", referenced from:
      _GetActiveDictionaryNames in main-dba0a1.o
      _main in main-dba0a1.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _GetDictionaryNameFromBundlePath in main-dba0a1.o
      _GetActiveDictionaryNames in main-dba0a1.o
      _main in main-dba0a1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Similar error message appears when I try to compile main.m file in ./example/ folder. I put them in the same folder and I have `symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` error again.

What am I doing wrong? The command in Terminal is `clang -framework CoreServices main.m -o main`.

Comment: You should show the rest of the error so that we can see what symbols are missing. And paste the code here so that we know it is the current version.

Comment: @MikeJfromVA, I have updated the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not finding "main", which means it does not know you are compiling a library rather than an executable. Add -dynamiclib to your clang options and you fix that one.

Those other missing functions are undocumented CoreServices functions. Add -framework CoreServices to fix these.

Then you have only warnings. :)

Comment: Even if I put main.m into the same directory as `TTTDictionary.m` and execute it as `clang -framework CoreServices main.m -o main` it gives me quite similar error. I will update my question to address the problem more fully.

Comment: You need both frameworks, like so: `clang -framework Foundation -framework CoreServices main.m TTTDictionary.m -o main`